# Advise on using an XML settings file in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am currently working on an Android application we developed internally, and which we deploy manually on customer tablets.

The app contains url's where to read/post the customers server data. Currently to deploy the app we need to change these url strings and recompile.

We are looking make the app more complete, and read these url's from outside the app. My thought was to have a xml settings file, which is downloaded with the app and the app reads from this.

I am fairly new to Android development, and would appreciate some advise.

If the xml file is downloaded to the download folder, can we copy this to where the android app is installed? Can the Android app read files outside of the .APK?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. At first, you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the folder for storing cache with [getFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()). Download the xml and place it in that folder. Then you can use it how much you want.

Comment: The .apk file is added to a website folder on IIS, so to download we open a browser on the tablet and use sitename.com/test.apk for example. The xml file would also download using the same approach sitename.com/test.xml. Would the test.xml be placed in the downloads folder on the device?

Comment: Could I get the installed app to copy the xml from downloads to where the application is installed? Would this be the best approach?

Comment: @snj15 No, that would be a bad approach. It is very likely that the download folder is on different places on different devices. If the url is different for each of your customer maybe you could display a popup the first time the app starts and ask for the url or the customer. Then download the file in the app to the app folder.

Comment: I thought I could use this code to access the download folder    File downloadFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

Comment: @snj15 That is unreliable. Apps have no obligation to store files in this directory, even if popular ones probably do. I wouldn't use that folder but if you do you should still move the downloaded file to the apps internal storage to prevent the user from deleting it.

Comment: My plan was to get the app to copy/move the xml file from the download. Would you possibly have any example code, on how to move/copy the file? If I use getFilesDir(), would this give me the location of the installed app?

Comment: I think writing a front-end admin activity would be a good idea for a future version. At the moment we just deploy the .apk by opening a browser on the Android device go to the customer url and the browser downloads the file. If I try this with an .xml in the browser will display the xml in the browser. Would I have get the xml from the browser cache? How else could I download the xml?